# Can not find jar dependency while compiling scala code into msil

Tags: .net, scala

I have a module named 'world' which depends on module 'hello'. Here is the project structure of 'world': 
[image]

where lib is the directory saving jar dependency and bin is the output directory for misl artifact.

I used the following command to compile it into misl :

```
SET SCALA_NET_DIRECTORY=E:\svn\scala-experimental\bootstrap
%SCALA_NET_DIRECTORY%\bin\scalacompiler.exe -Xassem-extdirs %SCALA_NET_DIRECTORY%\bin -target:msil -d bin -classpath %SCALA_NET_DIRECTORY%\lib\hello-1.0.jar src\main\scala\my\world\App.scala
```

where the `scalacompiler.exe` is from `svn co http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/svn-repos/scala/scala-experimental/trunk/bootstrap` experimental project.

And I got an error :

[image]

Could any Scala.Net expert give me a suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the options in your command line reads

```
-classpath %SCALA_NET_DIRECTORY%\lib\hello-1.0.jar
```

I guess you want first to compile hello-1.0 as a .dll (by not giving

```
-Xshow-class MyMainClass
```

in the command line) and then compile

```
src\main\scala\my\world\App.scala
```

(as an .exe, I guess) with hello-1.0.dll to be found in one of the  -Xassem-extdirs folders.

Tips and tricks on using Scala.Net at http://www.srtsolutions.com/tag/scala

Comment: But what if I need a third dependency, such as common-pool.jar?

Comment: Use -Xassem-extdirs multiple times, and each folder given in -Xassem-extdirs can contain several assemblies that the program being compiled depends on.

There's an example showing that at http://www.benbarefield.com/blog/?p=79 

Regarding 64bit, the CLR JIT compiler has thrown a couple of times exceptions that its 32bit counterpart hasn't (this is not fault of Scala.Net). One way to overcome this problem (till the JITter is fixed) is corflags <Executable name> /32Bit+